# "Calibrate" NSTimer for UI updates

Tags: ios, macos, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to implement a countdown feature for my program. It's a second-timer, so I use a `NSTimer` object with a time interval of 1.0 second to update the UI. But in order not to accumulate error (every 1.0-second interval will incur a little bit of lag), the program caculates the absolute difference between current time and beginning time for the remaining time displayed in the UI.

The problem is, after the `NSTimer` object runs for a significant time (say half an hour), it's no longer "synced" with the absolute time due to accumulated error: the UI update happens between two "absolute" seconds. For example, if the countdown starts at `00:00:00.000`, at first UI updates at `00:00:01.000`, `00:00:02.000` ... but after a while it becomes `00:30:03.567` or something like that.

Any idea how I can deal with this? Are there any other better ways to implement this? Thanks!

Comment: Why display the milliseconds if you're not counting them?

Comment: Depending on the source of the lag, a kind of "oversampling" might help: simply make the timer fire on a sub-second interval.

Comment: As @JoshCaswell said, run the timer faster and either don't display the milliseconds or just hard-code them to 0 if you want to have them displayed for some reason

Comment: @JoshCaswell @Paulw11 No the milliseconds are not displayed, I'm just using them as an example. The real problem is what __is__ displayed is the rounded (to second) result of the actual time, so if the `NSTimer` ends up somewhere in the middle, the displayed time may __stop updating for 1 sec__ or __jump 2 secs in one udpate__. Oversampling is a good idea, I'll try and see if the energy impact is acceptable. Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One high level idea is to detect when the timer is getting too far out of sync based on your absolute time calculation. When it gets past a specific threshold, say 0.01 seconds or whatever you desire, cancel the current timer and start a new one after an appropriate delay that gets it back "in sync".

Comment: Works like a charm. What I especially like about your idea is that it has extremely low energy impact. Thank you!